# log4js-node with ES module?

Tags: node.js, import, es6-modules, log4js-node

I am trying to set up log4js-node in my code.
As I want to write to the same log file from different .js files, I am setting it up in an external file as [per the documentation](https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/learn-nodejs-winston/#flexible-configuration-in-log4js):

```
const appSettings = {
        log4js: {
            traceLogConfig: {
                appenders: {
                    fileAppender: { type: 'file', filename: `./logs/${settings.custid}/${Date.now()}.log`},
                    consoleAppender: { type: 'console' }
                },
                categories: {
                    default: { appenders: ['fileAppender', 'consoleAppender'], level: 'trace'}
                }
            }
        }
    };
    
    module.exports = appSettings;
```

And in the files:

```
import log4js from 'log4js';

//Setting up logger
const { traceLogConfig } = require('./logs').log4js;
log4js.configure(traceLogConfig);
const logger = log4js.getLogger();
```

However, when I try to run the code, I get the following error message:

> const { traceLogConfig } = require('./logs').log4js;
> ^
>
> ReferenceError: require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use
> import instead This file is being treated as an ES module because it
> has a '.js' file extension and
> 'package.json' contains "type":
> "module". To treat it as a CommonJS script, rename it to use the
> '.cjs' file extension.

I don't know how to convert this structure (const { traceLogConfig } = require('./logs').log4js;) to ES6 modules.
I tried:

```
import {traceLogConfig} from './logs'.log4js
import {traceLogConfig} from './logs.log4js'
import {traceLogConfig} from './logs.js.log4js'
```

Usually, visual studio code gives me a small lamp that shows how to automatically convert it to ES6 module compatible code, but this time it doesn't show up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer.
You need to first import the whole file like this:

```
import appSettings from '../logs.js';
```

Then you need to reference the specific settings when you call it:

```
log4js.configure(appSettings.log4js.traceLogConfig);
```